# How to enable FileSystemObject to detect Extension-less files

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7.5, filesystemobject

This is a standard text/html file without any extension (ie: `c:\noextensionfile`), that has the proper Mime Type in place to serve it as a text/html, that does work on the client-side as it should, however, when I use the FileSystemObject object on the server-side to manipulate the file (move, delete, etc.) all I get is a 'File Not Found.' error.  I really don't know how to make this object detect an extension-less file.  I have the proper permissions set, b/c it works with an extension, but otherwise, I get a not found error.

Example:

```
   oFs.FileExists("c:\noextensionfile") <-- Is always False
   oFs.DeleteFile("c:\noextensionfile") <-- Returns: File Not Found
```

The file does exist, just not to the object. How do I work-around this, I need to use extension-less file names. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your file really in the root of the C: drive or in your site's web folders?

Comment: I tested this and `oFs.FileExists("f:\test\test1")` returns `true` in my example, even if the file test1 is empty (0 bytes).

Comment: Permissions. Classic ASP run with minimal permissions, don't try accessing the server root drive. Try with sub folders where you can manually change permissions without much risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const FILE = "C:\bootmgr"

Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo "File '" & FILE & "' exists? " & oFso.FileExists(FILE)
```

When saved to a file (say ***noext.vbs***) and run on my Windows 7 machine, I get:

```
File 'C:\bootmgr' exists? True
```

I'd think you'd get a similar result within your ASP Classic script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but you could try to use `OpenTextFile` without extension (because here a file is expected) and then work from there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx